# Javascript ..cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

Can anyone explain this program:
I`am unable to understand setcookie function.
Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
  {
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function checkCookie()
{
var username=getCookie("username");
if (username!=null && username!="")
  {
  alert("Welcome again " + username);
  }
else 
  {
  username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");
  if (username!=null && username!="")
    {
    setCookie("username",username,365);
    }
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="checkCookie()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code example you posted is incomplete, and your general grammar makes it very difficult to understand you.

Comment: You need to separate your code from your markup. This is easily one of the most important things you can learn in development. Notice the helpful error warnings you get when you put your script in the proper place. http://jsbin.com/AJAzEmI/2/edit

Answer (score 2):

You pass a name, value and number of days to the function setCookie.
This creates a cookie with the given name and value, that will expire in the configured number of days time.